# Why does codesigned Go binary get tagged as “Unknown Developer” on macOS 13?

Tags: macos, go, launchd, codesign, launch-daemon

The current macOS 13 beta has a feature in which it displays all  application-installed Login Items in a System Preferences panel, including LaunchDaemons.  My app has a LaunchDaemon written in Go that I `codesign` with my Developer ID as part of the build process.

But when I view the Login Items in System Preferences on macOS 13 with only my app installed, I see this:

[image: unknown developer display]

I am sure the circled binary is codesigned correctly. For example, here is the output of `spctl` after an Xcode archive build (`tless` is the go binary):

```
% spctl -vvv -a -t open --context context:primary-signature mactless/Applications/Mactless.app/Contents/Resources/tless
mactless/Applications/Mactless.app/Contents/Resources/tless: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: MY_NAME_HERE (SB********)
```

The `SB********` is my correct Developer ID signing identity.

What could be the cause of macOS 13 identifying this signed binary as being from an "unknown developer”?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that displays my Developer ID name in place of "Unknown Developer."  I set all of the following values equal to `com.mycompany.MyApp.daemon`:

- The name of the binary itself
- (The codesign Run Script step thus also became `codesign -s [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] -o runtime -v com.mycompany.MyApp.daemon`)
- The Label field inside the /Library/LaunchDaemons plist file
- The name of the /Library/LaunchDaemons plist file (with `.plist` at the end, i.e., `com.mycompany.MyApp.daemon.plist`)

Rebuilt, uninstalled and reinstalled, and voila, it showed up with my name where the circle is instead of Unknown Developer.

Hope this helps someone.